# Possible collision between nodejs and angular routing

Tags: node.js, angular

First of all I have a lot of experience working with HTML/CSS and browser Javascript (including AngularJS)

Now I started using NodeJS and also Angular(2).

Upto now I would have *sworn* that it is not possible to omit the hash character (or any similar character) from client routing, because (I thought) it would always go to the server for routing in that case.

Example: I have a nodejs express application which sends index.html when issuing a GET on `/`

Then there is a (client side) Angular app, which has its own routing with no hash character. So for example when I access `/myroute` from within the client app, it will use Angular routing to determine the view template that should be presented to the user.

I don't get that. Why doesn't it go to the server to determine the route? Also, if I enter the URL directly in the browser (including `/myroute`) it still manages to route using Angular.

What happens when I add a server side route to `/myroute`?

I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a rudimentary answer. I will edit it to make it better if this is what we are looking for:

You click inside the app, then using locationProvider and HTML5 History API angular takes over navigation attempts and handles it internally using Angular Router

Directly, navigating using the address bar means the browser tries to fetch the page from the server directly and angular cannot override. So, the solution is simple URL rewriting. If in your case its node, you will do something like `app.all()` to redirect all requests back to the index file where your angular app resides. Then the client side router takes over from there.

And yes, if the same route exists at both point, you'll need to make a logic at the server to decide whether you give control back to angular or not. Simple solution, I use is that all the server routes start with `/api` so except for `/api/*` routes all reenter back to the angular start point.

Comment: Awesome!! Happy to help!